# google apps script for conditional color formatting of one cell based on another cell's value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to put together a google apps script that changes the font color of of a cell based on the value of another cell. If cell B2 > D2, change the font color of B2 to red. Problem is that I have no experience with javascript...so the little script I copy pasted and edited together doesn't work.

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var columnO = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var oValues = columnO.getValues();
  var column1 = sheet.getRange(2, 4, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var oValues1 = columnO.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {
    if (oValues[i][0] > oValues1[i][0]) {
      sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 1).setFontColors('red');
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to extend this script to be able to do: if B2 > D2 color red and if B2 < C2 color blue, otherwise color green.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing I see is a mistake/typo on line 6: `column0.getValues()` should be `column1.getValues()`.

Another error is on the for-loop, where you `getRange(i, 1, 1, 1)`. On your question you wrote you want to change `B2` cell color and this statement is changing column `A`. Also, the row index should start on 2, not 0.

Another important thing to consider on a script like this is to use batch functions, as it will speed it up greatly, e.g.

```js
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues(); //B, C and D
  var colors = [];  

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    colors.push([values[i][0] > values[i][2] ? 'red' :
                 values[i][0] < values[i][2] ? 'blue' : 'green']);
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, colors.length, 1).setFontColors(colors);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to run this automatically whenever I update columns B, C and D?

Comment: Yes there is. Please take a look here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Simple