# Conditional formatting based on another cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm using Google Sheets for a daily dashboard.  What I need is to change the background color of cell B5 based on the value of another cell - C5.  If C5 is greater than 80% then the background color is green but if it's below, it will be amber/red.

Is this available with a Google Sheets function or do I need to insert a script?

Comment: Until you move to the new Sheets, adapt one of the scripts from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17561979/1677912) using an `onEdit` trigger or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11857110/1677912) which doesn't.

Answer (score 584, accepted):

**Note:** when it says "B5" in the explanation below, it actually means "B{current_row}", so for C5 it's B5, for C6 it's B6 and so on. Unless you specify $B$5 - then you refer to one specific cell.

---

This is supported in Google Sheets as of 2015:
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/78413#formulas

In your case, you will need to set conditional formatting on B5.

- Use the "**Custom formula is**" option and set it to `=B5>0.8*C5`.
- set the "**Range**" option to `B5`.
- set the desired color

You can repeat this process to add more colors for the background or text or a color scale.

Even better, make a single rule apply to all rows by using ranges in "**Range**". Example assuming the first row is a header:

- On B2 conditional formatting, set the "**Custom formula is**" to `=B2>0.8*C2`.
- set the "**Range**" option to `B2:B`.
- set the desired color

Will be like the previous example but works on all rows, not just row 5.
Ranges can also be used in the "Custom formula is" so you can color an entire row based on their column values.

Comment: Thank you Zig for letting me know.  It's useful however can't just use it unless I copy my old spreadsheet version content to the new one.  Thanks buddy

Comment: For speed I recommend migrating to the new sheets, but wait a bit as its on early beta and some things aren't fully supported yet.

Comment: I don't understand how to use the range directly in the custom formula field. If I want cells B5-B10 to have a color depending on cell C5, I cannot figure out how to express that.

Comment: I figured it out, you need to use an absolute reference. For example, "=B5:B10=C$5" in the forumla, and B5:B10 in the range.

Comment: yes, if you dont want the reference to move for the other cells.

Comment: To reference a cell on another sheet: `=B2>0.8*indirect("Sheet1!C2")` ([source](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/ywlxpiPiTgE/Fd7dFsfJnEMJ))

Comment: You don't need the custom formula. You can just use the Greater Than option. In the value/formula box, enter the cell reference. Just bear in mind that the cell reference is *relative* without the $, so if you are trying to get multiple cells to change color based on one cell, you need to use an absolute reference: $C$5

Comment: @Zig Mandel Works ok except for cells formatted as currencies, im just trying to hide (fore/background white) range of cells, some of which are currency. Any idea how? cheers

Comment: @Tom Thanks for letting me know it's relative. It really doesn't look like that when inputting it, but it behaves like relative. I was afraid that I had to add one for each 45 columns, but I'm glad I didn't have to.

Comment: It appears you can only do this for the "Single colour" tab, and not for the "Colour scale" tab, unfortunately. Unless someone knows of a way, it looks like you would have to to manually create a colour scale by putting in each colour individually (and you wouldn't get the smooth colour fade effect).

Answer (score 216):

One more example:

If you have Column from A to D, and need to highlight the whole line (e.g. from A to D) if B is "Complete", then you can do it following:

```
"Custom formula is":  =$B:$B="Completed" 
Background Color:     red 
Range:                A:D
```

Of course, you can change Range to A:T if you have more columns.

If B contains "Complete", use search as following:

```
"Custom formula is":  =search("Completed",$B:$B) 
Background Color:     red 
Range:                A:D
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unless you provide `$` in the "Custom Formula Is" field. i.e. do `$B$2:$B` and not `B2:B`

Comment: Just to add to lucky1928's answer -- if you change Range from A:D to A:T you will be adding more columns, not lines/rows. If you only have a finite number of rows you want the conditional formatting to work on then it may help to specify a row, e.g. A2:D13 if you have a header row for example. Otherwise if you are matching to something being either blank or not equal to a specific value, you may be adding colour to all rows that exist in the sheet, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Note that the "=" at the beginning of the formula is *VERY IMPORTANT*

Answer (score 20):

I've used an interesting conditional formatting in a recent file of mine and thought it would be useful to others too.
So this answer is meant for completeness to the previous ones.

It should demonstrate what this amazing feature is capable of, and especially how the $ thing works.

### Example table

[image: Simple google sheets table]

The color from D to G depend on the values in columns A, B and C. But the formula needs to check values that are fixed horizontally (user, start, end), and values that are fixed vertically (dates in row 1). That's where the dollar sign gets useful.

### Solution

There are 2 users in the table, each with a defined color, respectively foo (blue) and bar (yellow).
We have to use the following conditional formatting rules, and apply both of them on the same range (`D2:G3`):

1. `=AND($A2="foo", D$1>=$B2, D$1<=$C2)`
2. `=AND($A2="bar", D$1>=$B2, D$1<=$C2)`

In English, the condition means:
*User is `name`, and date of current cell is after `start` and before `end`*

Notice how the only thing that changes between the 2 formulas, is the name of the user. This makes it really easy to reuse with many other users!

### Explanations

> **Important**: Variable rows and columns are relative to the start of the range. But fixed values are not affected.

It is easy to get confused with relative positions. In this example, if we had used the range `D1:G3` instead of `D2:G3`, the color formatting would be shifted 1 row up.
To avoid that, remember that **the value for variable rows and columns should correspond to the start of the containing range**.

In this example, the range that contains colors is `D2:G3`, so the start is `D2`.

**`User`, `start`, and `end` vary with rows**
-> Fixed columns A B C, variable rows starting at 2: `$A2`, `$B2`, `$C2`

**`Dates` vary with columns**
-> Variable columns starting at D, fixed row 1: `D$1`

Comment: This probably needs a separate post, but is it possible to base the conditional styling itself off of another cell?  e.g. if you have a separate lookup table for your guys "foo" and "bar", can Conditional Formatting be configured to apply the fg-color & bg-color of that cell in your rule? 

This is something I need often, a "status" indicator for a row, where the colors and status options are easily configured without manual reprogramming of the conditional formatting rules.

Comment: You may be able to do that with scripting. I reckon I've never seen a dynamic mean to select specific colors or an existing format through normal usage. EDIT: to start scripting go to tools > script editor and start coding. But that's a whole new level in using sheets ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Basically all you need to do is add $ as prefix at column letter and row number. Please see image below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> change the background color of cell B5 based on the value of another cell - C5. If C5 is greater than 80% then the background color is green but if it's below, it will be amber/red.

There is no mention that B5 contains any value so assuming `80%` is `.8` formatted as percentage without decimals and blank counts as "below":

Select B5, colour "amber/red" with standard fill then Format - Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is and:

```
=C5>0.8
```

with green fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

[image: CF rule example]

Answer (score 4):

I'm disappointed at how long it took to work this out.

I want to see which values in my range are outside standard deviation.

1. Add the standard deviation calc to a cell somewhere `=STDEV(L3:L32)*2`
2. Select the range to be highlighted, right click, conditional formatting
3. Pick *Format Cells if Greater than*
4. In the *Value or Formula* box type `=$L$32` (whatever cell your stdev is in)

I couldn't work out how to put the STDEv inline. I tried many things with unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to explain it in a another way. In "custom formula" conditional formatting you have  two important fields:

- Custom formula
- Apply to

Let's say, you have a simple sheet with test percentages of students, where you want to color Student Ids(Column B) where their score(Column C) > 80%:

| Row | B(Student ID) | C(Score) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 48189 | 98% |
| 2 | 9823 | 6% |
| 3 | 17570 | 40% |
| 4 | 60968 | 23% |
| 5 | 69936 | 7% |
| 6 | 8276 | 59% |
| 7 | 15682 | 96% |
| 8 | 95977 | 31% |

To design a custom formula, you only need to design a formula **for the top left of the range**, you want to color. In this case, that would be `B1`.

The formula should return

- `TRUE`, if it should be colored and
- `FALSE`, if it shouldn't be colored

For B1, the formula would then be:

```
=C1>80%
```

Now imagine that you put that  formula in B1(Or just use a another range to test it). It would be like:

| Row | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |

Now imagine dragging the formula(or autofill) up to `B8` from `B1`. This is how it would look like

| Row | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |  |
| 2 | FALSE |  |
| 3 | FALSE |  |
| 4 | FALSE |  |
| 5 | FALSE |  |
| 6 | FALSE |  |
| 7 | TRUE |  |
| 8 | FALSE |  |

This translates directly to color `B1` and `B7`. **Now the interesting thing is All of this is autocalculated using the given formula for `B1` and the `Apply to` range.**  If you fill:

- Custom formula: `=C1>80%` and
- Apply to: `B1:B8`

you're saying

- Fill the custom formula `=C1>80%`
- in the top left cell of the provided range `B1:B8`,i.e., `B1` and
- drag/autofill the formula  to the whole range `B1:B8` and
- Color the cells, where the formula outputs `TRUE`

If you want to color both student IDs and score, you would use

- Custom formula:

  ```
  =$C1>80%
  ```
- Apply to:

  ```
  B1:C8
  ```

The `$` in the `$C1` says not to change `C`, when autofilling the range. In the imaginary table(I suggest you to output the table somewhere). This would look like:

| Row | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | TRUE |
| 2 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 5 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 6 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 7 | TRUE | TRUE |
| 8 | FALSE | FALSE |

In this way, you can color any cell anywhere based on any other cell.