# How to make [Conditional Formatting] script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want,

If Sheet1 ColumnB = Sheet89 ColumnA

Then matched Sheet1 Column B cells will be green
Here is my [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14DNpNtzcbe5956wC5lwAJ0nPFPbgqutra6bzcc5Qi-4/edit#gid=0).

Based on some guideline I made this but not working.

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var columnB = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var bValues = columnB.getValues();
  var sheet89 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet89');
  var columnO = sheet89.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
  var oValues = columnO.getValues();

        for (var h = 0; h < bValues.length; h++) {
           for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {
              if (oValues[i][0] == bValues[h][0]) {
                 sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('green');
              }
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: The new google sheets allow you to do this without gas, using conditional formatting with ranges

Comment: @ZigMandel is it possible to use conditional formatting across sheets?

Comment: see here for an example on how to compare against values in other cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value/20547577#20547577

Comment: @Zig Mandel: New sheet does not allow VLOOKUP formula. What I'm expecting to get. Its allow some basic function only.

Answer (score 0):

This solution below will iterate through each cell with a value in column B of sheet1 and check it against every value in Column A of sheet89 (although you named this ColumnO, according to your getValues function, it will grab values from Column A).

If it finds a match, it will turn green the cell in column B of sheet1.  In your example code you use the i loop variable (which iterates through rows on sheet89) to get the cell on sheet1 to turn green.  It's not clear which cells you want to turn green.  I assumed it was the cells on sheet1 so I changed the the code to

```
sheet.getRange(h+1, 2).setBackgroundColor('green');
```

Also, the getRange function for a single cell only requires 2 arguments, so I removed the numRows and numColumns arguments for the line which colors the cell green.

I'm not sure why bValues and oValues exclude the last row, but I removed the -1 in each of these as it will cause the code to fail if for any reason it is run on a blank worksheet.  The getLastRow() returns the last row with a value, not the next blank row in the sheet.  If you want to capture the whole sheet, then you shouldn't use -1.

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var columnB = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var bValues = columnB.getValues();

  var sheet89 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet89');
  var columnO = sheet89.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var oValues = columnO.getValues();

  for (var h = 0; h < bValues.length; h++) {
     for (var i = 0; i < oValues.length; i++) {

       if (oValues[i][0] == bValues[h][0]) {
         sheet.getRange(h + 1, 2).setBackgroundColor('green');
       }  
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand to be required (and not what the example sheet shows at present) is possible with Conditional formatting.

In Google Spreadsheets conditional formatting across sheets is not nearly as straightforward as within a single sheet, because of security and therefore authorisation. You may, for speed for example, prefer to copy the content of `Sheet89` into `Sheet1` (just two cells) to avoid that issue, or indeed write a script instead. At least keep the ranges as small as practical.

However it is possible, though may be slow and require authorisation.

Please clear any conditional formatting from `Sheet1 ColumnA` then:

Select ColumnA in `Sheet1`, Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=countif(IMPORTRANGE(" k e y ","Sheet89!A:A"),A1)<>0
```

with highlighting of your choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

`k e y` above represents the unique identification code for `Sheet89` (will look something like `1u4vq8vDne-aKMVdJQPREGOxx7n99FqIb_kuJ_bG-PzM`).

The image shows at present what is in ColumnC of the image (but is in ColumnA of the example) and F1 and F2 in the image show what is in ColumnA of `Sheet89` of the example. The paler brown has been applied with Conditional formatting::

[image: SO20889520 example]