# Conditional Formatting based on two different cell values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I want to color a specific cell if (for example):

- A1 has a value (meaning it is not blank)
- B1 has no value (meaning it is blank)

In this scenario I would like to color B1 red.
I want the formula to apply to the entirety of the B-column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Based on another Cell Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value)

Comment: When I said that I want this to apply to the entirety of the B-column I meant the following:

A1 has value
B1 has no value
> make B1 red

A2 has value
B2 has no value
> make B2 red

A3 has value
B3 has no value
> make B3 red

Answer (score 6):

Try clicking Format > Conditional formatting > Custom formula is:

`=AND($A1<>"";$B1="")`

Apply this to range B:B and select a red colour format

Comment: This didn't work. It says "Invalid Formula"

Comment: here is an example sheet (https://goo.gl/HfSDKA) with the formula applied to column B

Comment: Also, your locale might not support the comma, try a semi-colon instead.

Comment: That did it. Needed a semi-colon instead. Thanks @AdamL.