# Conditionally formatting a range based on a specific cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have the below table:

```
A1=100

Company     A     B     C  .........
Microsoft   134   51    91
Google      14    532   215
Samsung     1     111   133
.
.
.
```

I wish that only the values that are greater than A1 will be highlighted in green.

EDIT: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value), although looks very similar, do not solve the problem above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Based on another Cell Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value)

Comment: RoyEsh, it would help if you'd [edit] your question to explain WHY that other answer does not apply to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Please select entire sheet, Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., **greater than**:

```
=$A$1
```

select green and <kbd>Done</kbd>.