# Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Based on 2 Cell Values

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm using Google spreadsheet as an overview of our outgoing invoices. If the invoice is paid, it's green and I add the date of payment. If not, it's red(column B) and empty. Column C has the invoice date in it and column D the expiration date.

How can I make the specific cell in column B turn orange when the payment hasn't been payed and the expiration date has been exceeded?

And yes, I've read the answers on the question [Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Based on another Cell Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value)

Comment: I think this covers it http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/85627/conditional-formatting-with-multiple-criteria-for-a-range-of-cells

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data as in the image and that the current date is 2017:

[image: SO40487849 example]

Clear any conditional formatting from ColumnB and apply standard red fill to it. With ColumnB selected: Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Cell is not empty` with green fill. Add another rule with `Custom formula is:`

```
=D1<today()
```

select orange fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

This is an unconventional colour scheme so you might want to consider switching red and orange.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, your header is :

Paid Date (col B); Invoice Date (col C); Expiration Date (col D).

You want to add conditional formatting and choose "Format cell if ..." : **Custom formula is**

Then enter the formula :

```
 = D2 > Today()
```

Answer (score 0):

`=AND(B4="", C4<TODAY())`

That formula changes C4 if B4 is empty AND C4 is before today's date.