# Conditional formatting a cell to change color based on the content of a cell in another tab

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

In Tab1, I want a cell (lets call it A1) to turn red if the number in a cell (say... B1) on Tab2 is negative.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I've spent the last hour researching on the same issue with no result :( Apparently using another tab's cell content cannot at this point be formatted via a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Select `Tab1` A1 then Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., Custom formula is:

```
=indirect("Tab2!B"&1)<0
```

choose red fill and click <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

See [Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting Based on another Cell Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value?rq=1) for how to do this.

If you want to reference a cell from a different tab you would write `'Tab Name'!B2` instead of just `B2`, where `'Tab Name'` is the name of the tab that you are referencing.

Comment: My problem is not in referencing another tab, but in figuring out what formula will tell the cell to change color.