# Google sheet - how to set conditional formatting on a cell block using a cell value outside of block

Tags: spreadsheet

I'm a Google sheet newbie. I'm trying to work out how to set a conditional formatting 'greater than' rule for a cell block where the criteria value is outside the block.  I've seen elsewhere that the solution requires a custom rule but I can't understand how to build the equation.

The cell block is: H10: M64.
The criteria value is at cell 'I6'

What equation do I set to force the conditional formatting to apply at a cell level within the H10:M64 block, so that if the cell value is greater than the value at 'I6' the conditional formatting will apply?

Comment: you should defenitely have look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is *absolute* vs. *relative* cell references.

### A primer on absolute vs. relative cell references

If you write a formula in cell `A3` that says `=A1*2`, that reference is *relative*. If you copy your formula into cell `B3`, it now says `=B1*2`.

You can keep this from happening and always refer to the exact same cell, no matter where you copy the same formula, with absolute cell references. Add `$` before the row and column references to lock the formula in on the same cell reference. If your original formula says `=$A$1*2`, then when you copy it over to cell `B3` then the formula stays exactly the same: `=$A$1*2`.

You can also just freeze either the row or the column, referencing `$A1` (So the row will shift relatively, but will always refer to column `A`) or `A$1` (the columns will shift relatively, but will always refer to row `1`).

### How this relates

In your conditional formatting rule, you want every cell in the range to be compared to the exact same cell: `$I$6`. But how do you get every separate cell in the range `H10:M64` to compare itself to `$I$6`? Relative cell references.

**Write your custom formula like so:**
`=H10>$I$6`

By comparing the *relative cell reference* for the top-left cell(`H10`) in the range to the *absolute cell reference* for `$I$6`, The formula will compare every cell relative to `H10` in the range to the same comparison cell and format accordingly:
`H10>$I$6`,
`H11>$I$6`,
`...`,
`M64>$I$6`

**Screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]