# Conditional formatting based on previous cell

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a list of times in a table that I want to apply some conditional formatting to. I just want them to turn different colours based on whether they're later or earlier than the time in the previous cell. I'm having trouble figuring out the appropriate rule though.

[image: conditional formatting rules]

More specifically I'm having trouble thinking of a formula for the rule that I can apply to the whole range of times given in the table. What I need is basically the condition `=[current cell]>[current cell-1]` and vice versa but don't know how to write this in a formula that I can apply as a rule for the whole range.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Conditional format rules on a range are propagated with autofill style reference updates. So if you select b1:d1 and say "after a1", this is different than if you say "after $a$1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Formula:

```
=B1<A1
```

Apply to:

```
B1:Z1
```

or

```
B:Z
```

Color:Green

Add another conditional formula for Red.

---

See [my detailed explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635326/)

Comment: Maybe add some explanation about why / how the formula works?