# Copying conditional formatting in google sheets references old rules rather then make new ones

Tags: google-sheets

Hi I was wondering how to copying conditional formatting rules to a new cell without the copied rules just referencing the old rules. Like actually create a new set of rules specific to that cell, rather then extending the range on the old rules. I'm not even sure why this was thought to be a good idea. It only works against you.

[image: The range (eg, B9:B10) is what happens instead of unique rules.]

Comment: `actually create a new set of rules specific to that cell, rather then extending the range on the old rules` WHY?

Comment: Because, I need to reference A32 for the cell below, but this rule is limited to A31

Comment: Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value