# Conditionally format a range based on a different range

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Given the sheet:

```
A| B | C = SUM($D2:$Z2) | D | E | F | ...
```

How would I, for a range of rows (for example: `4:50`), color columns `Cx:Zx` (for row `x`) if `Bx > Cx`, without making a conditional rule for each individual row and/or each individual column?

(Assume there are a lot of rows and a lot of columns.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several Q&A on Stackoverflow that would assist you. In particular [Conditional formatting based on another cell's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-value) and the answer (with the attached comments) by Zig Mandel. It's a reminder that some Googling is always worthwhile before asking a new question.

- Select "Custom formatting" from the Format menu.
- Set "Apply to Range" to C2:Z50
- "Format cells if", select "Custom formula is" and enter `=$B2:$B>$C2:$C`
- Select Done.

---

**B is less than C**
[image: B is less than C]

---

**B is greater than C**
[image]

Screen shots

Comment: That is true, but none answered fully with regard to upper left and lower right range bounds with end range of full column in the custom formula. Thank you; I believe that your answer is original and more robust than others provided.

Comment: @kando You may be right, but I'm not sure. The BIG thing revealed in that Q&A was the use of the '$' sign in the custom formula. I had to experiment with combinations to have the condition apply to a whole row, but I haven't seen _any_ discussion else on that topic. What I'm saying is sometimes another question may not necessarily resolve one's question, but it may provides a key; in fact, it may take a few other questions to "join the dots".