# Color coding (conditional formatting) the whole row based on value of a single column in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have some data in a google spreadsheet.
It looks like-

```
+----+--------------+---------+
|user|cos_similarity|item_rank|
+----+--------------+---------+
|  u1|   0.004437351|        1|
|  u1|  0.0043772724|        2|
|  u1|   0.004322561|        3|
|  u1|   0.004322561|        3|
|  u2|   0.004557799|        1|              
|  u2|   0.004471699|        1|               
|  u2|  0.0043906723|        1|              
|  u2|  0.0043018474|        2|         
|  u2|  0.0042955037|        3|         
+----+--------------+---------+
```

I want to color-code the spreadsheet (all the rows) conditioned on the values present in a column named 'item_rank'.

So the whole row gets it's color from the value in the 'item_rank' column. The colors are supposed to reflect groups which I am defining by the value in a particular column.

Expected output-

```
Rows 1, 5, 6 should be having the same color because they have 'item_rank'=1.
Rows 2, 8 should be having the same color because they have 'item_rank'=2.
Rows 3, 4, 9 should be having the same color because they have 'item_rank'=3.
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional formatting based on another cell's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this formula variation for range A2:C:

```
=$C2=1
```

[image]

Comment: whats the significance of 2 in C2? solution worked btw

Comment: @n0obcoder thats the starting position/row. so C2 is starting row of range C2:C (or A2:C in your case)

Comment: how can I write custom rule for odd and even values. Suppose I want the rows to be colored in 2 colors only. yellow if the item_rank for that row is odd, else green. What do I achieve this? @player0

Comment: @n0obcoder can you share a copy of your sheet with some example of desired result?

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I used the custom formula '=isodd(Value($C2))' for coloring all the rows with odd value in 'item_rank' column.