# Excel function if one cell has 'X' then gray out the other and viceversa. If not, leave blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Looking to see if there is a way on Excel to do an `If` with a rule that grays out the other cell.

Basically, if one cell (out of 2 columns) gets an X, gray out the other one automatically. If they both don't have anything, leave them blank.
Is there a way to do this? I've attached a snapshot:

[image: Example]

Comment: `a rule that grays out the other cell` - no, but it's trivial with [conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) to gray out *this cell* based on the state of other cells, which is what you want expressed the other way round.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-value

Answer (score 0):

**YES - THERE IS A WAY !**

Select c3:d6 per screenshot (1st table) and then enter this formula for the conditional formatting rule:

```
=SUM(1*(IFERROR(UNICODE($C3:$D3),0)=88))*(C3="")
```

[image: Cell references for main function "X" and varants/mods]

Notes:

- *applicable for "X" per your 2nd sentence*
- *assumes no shading if both cells contain "X"*

---

Unequivocally, this is a *'rule/function that grays out one of the cells is the other has an "X" '*, or, per original Q:

> *"if one cell (out of 2 columns) gets an X, gray out the other one automatically... is there a [i.e. any] way to do this?"*

---

**Mods:**

1] For any non-blank (not just "X"):

```
 =SUM(1*($C3:$D3<>""))*(C3="")
```

2] Case insensitive variant (i.e. allow "X" or "x"):

```
=SUM(1*($C3:$D3="x"))*(C3="")
```

*(sum function treats "X" the same as "x", so could use either for this mod)*

---

References: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) (unicodes)