# filter out duplicate records with 0 instance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below data set in excel which I am trying to filter out based on the value in next column.

What I am trying to do here is if there is any 0 values present in SH-001, the whole record set will filter out from the list.

Data

| Stye | Inventory |
| --- | --- |
| SH-001 | 1 |
| SH-001 | 1 |
| SH-001 | 0 |
| SH-002 | 2 |
| SH-002 | 3 |
| SH-002 | 4 |

Desired out put

| Style | Inventory |
| --- | --- |
| SH-002 | 2 |
| SH-002 | 3 |
| SH-002 | 4 |

Any suggestions will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Conditional Formatting in Excel. Assuming that the columns "Style" & "Inventory" are in column A & B respectively in your excel, you need to apply the following conditional formatting on entire column A

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,0)>0
```

This will highlight all the cells that match the above condition. Then you can use "Filter by color" feature in excel.

[image: Sample Screenshot showing conditional formatting]

Comment: Thanks, can we also add one more criteria to it

Comment: You can add as many criterias as you'd like to. You should be able to find some resources online

Answer (score 2):

Next solution - using FILTER-function (Office 365) and defined table (insert table > named tblData).

`=FILTER(tblData;MINIFS(tblData[Inventory];tblData[Stye];tblData[Stye])<>0)`

[image]

`MINIFS(tblData[Inventory];tblData[Stye];tblData[Stye])` acts like a helper column to tblData that returns per each row the min-value of the according Stye - which then can be used for the main filter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you; it's for Googles spreadsheets, but the way to go is probably similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25903892/3249027
The linked example is about conditional formatting and not filtering per se, but you could "format" the data of the undesired set by multiplying it with zero `*0` and then simply filter all `0`s in a next step.