# Compose a formula for filtering column (.whenFormulaSatisfied(……) )

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column with names. (Example: Mike worked - 3 times, then John - 2 times, then again Mike .. etc.). Groups of names are vertically separated by an empty row (Fig. 1).
I want to run the filter by app script on a specific name - let's say Mike. But in the received data, I need the groups of names Mike to be vertically separated by ONLY one empty row - not like (in Fig. 2).
I think it is possible to discard extra empty rows by applying the formula - I showed an example of its work in column 2 (Fig. 3). But I don't understand how to write such a formula in my code (and is it possible at all ?) ! :

```
var textToFilter = "Mike";
var FilterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenFormulaSatisfied("=AND(A1:A1000=" + "\"" + textToFilter + "\"" + ")");
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, FilterCriteria);
```

[Fig.1][image: 1]

[Fig.2][image: 2]

[Fig.3][image: 3]

Comment: Why can't you use the function `=filter(A:A,A:A="Mike")` (or some cell that's driving the filter)? Throw that function in cell `c2` or something and see if that's what you're going for?

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do it via app script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like [conditional formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635326/), you only need to reference the starting row, which is always the second row (after the header row as mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437887/compose-a-formula-for-filtering-column-whenformulasatisfied/73442277#comment129703002_73442277) by [alex che](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19359430/alex-che)), in case of a filter. The formula is automatically propagated to the filtered data range.  Therefore, If the filter starts at A1, the formula should be

```
=OR(A2="Mike", AND(A2="", A3="Mike"))
```

```
const textToFilter = "Mike";
const FilterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp
  .newFilterCriteria()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied(
    `=OR(A2="${textToFilter}",
     AND(A2="", A3="${textToFilter}"))`
  );
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, FilterCriteria);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question.
I'm sure the solution is close, but something is missing (maybe a range in my formula, maybe a $ symbol somewhere).
I tried code - but I didn't get filtering by Mike - (Fig. 4)
Please see my edited question above.

Comment: Yes, I saw that there were not enough quotes at first.
But with your fix it WORKED ! !
Thanks again!

Comment: My important remark - otherwise there will be a problem!
The cells in the formula (their rows) must be NEXT after the row declared as the beginning of the filtering range.
For example 23 is the initial row of the filtering range - then A24 and A25 will be the cells in this formula!!