# Google Sheets Scripts - bold row when cell equals value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set an entire row (columns a:w) in a sheet to **bold** when the value in column C = "NEW#####".  I'm struggling with how to get the whole row **bold**.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FormTest");
var range = sheet.getRange("A:W");
sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=$C="NEW#####"')
  .setBold(true)
  .setRanges([range])
  .build();
var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule1);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

Comment: `'=$C1="NEW#####"'`

Comment: Thanks, I made that update but it’s still not bolding the entire row (or even the cell that holds the value).

Comment: Make sure [you understand the basics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635326/) and are able to do what you want through the user interface first.

Comment: Thanks, my use case doesn’t allow the use of basic conditional formatting in this case.

Comment: ? There's no advanced conditional formatting.  There's only one. Just basic conditional formatting.