# How to have Column A's color be changed by one separate Column? (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get Column A's color to be changed by what Column E's text.
Like an example is if Column E has **English** it would change cause Column A's color to be changed to something like purple. What script would be used to this to get this to happen? I am trying to get this to apply so all of Column E applies to **all** of Column A.

Comment: No need for a script, you can use [conditional formatting](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/conditional-formatting-google-sheets).

Comment: @CherryDT How would I get it so it for all of both columns? Like having all of the E column effect all of the A column? Looking at the blog post you linked, it makes it seem like it only applies to ONE row in the two columns.

Comment: You can apply conditional formatting to all cells in column A and write the condition so that it references `$E1`, i.e. `E` is fixed but `1` will be relative, so on `A1` it will reference `E1`, on `A2` it will reference `E2`, and so on - like any other formula

Comment: Please  spend a few hours [reading the duplicate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635326/) and experimenting.