# Data validation to Put values in column based on condition

Tags: date, validation, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make condition for data vlidation in Google Sheets but i am stuck that how it can be achieve.

Let me explain it. Data validation will be applied on Column `A` based on adjacent 4 columns value.

I have achieved one of them that if mentioned columns are not empty then you will be able to put a value in column `A` but i want that if that condition achieved then one can only put `Date` like `DD/MM/YYYY` in such format

```
=AND($B$3:$B$700<>"",$C$3:$C$700<>"",$D$3:$D$700<>"",$E$3:$E$700<>"")
```

But i need to create one more condition that if Column `B` is not empty then we can add only `"P"` into Column `A`.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Result Required like in columnA**

| columnA | columB | columC | columD | columE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/11/2022 | 256 | MNO | 256 | POP |
| condition not met | JKL |  |  | POP |
| condition not met | POP | MNO | MNO |  |
| 25/11/2022 | JKL | POP | 256 | JKL |
| condition not met | 257 | MNO | 257 |  |
| condition not met | JKL |  |  | POP |
| P | POP |  |  |  |
| condition not met | JKL |  | 257 | JKL |
| P | 258 |  |  |  |

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qUU5rmkLe-JqmSAwi-5bTV5JoogiDLPavBGGy8GiEkw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: I added a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=(ISDATE(A2)*(B2<>"")*(C2<>"")*(D2<>"")*(E2<>""))+((A2="P")*(B2<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($B2<>"",IF(AND($B2:$E2<>""),ISDATE($A2),$A2="P")))
```

If `B2` is not empty,

- and if `B2:E2` is not empty,

  - check if A2 is a date
  - else check if A2="P"

If you want to enforce strict `dd/mm/yyyy`, use `REGEX`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($B2<>"",IF(AND($B2:$E2<>""),REGEXMATCH(""&$A2,"[0-9]{2}/(0[1-9]|1[1-2])/\d{4}"),$A2="P")))
```

##### Apply to:

```
A2:A
```

Data validation formula, like conditional formatting [gets applied to all the cells as if it's drag filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-value/69635326#69635326).