# Conditional formatting duplicates with two conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

We have the following data

|  | Col. B | Col. C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | noun | spring |
| 4 | ver. | spring |
| 5 | ver. | spring |

We need rows 4 and 5 (both columns `B` and `C`) to turn red because they are duplicates

We have tried

`=(COUNTIF(B$3:B377,B3)>1)*(COUNTIF(C$3:C377,C3)>1)`

`=AND((COUNTIF(B$3:B377,B3)>1),(COUNTIF(C$3:C377,C3)>1))`

`=COUNTIF(B$3:B377&C$3:C377,B3&C3)>1`

but cannot make it work.

Using  `=COUNTIFS(B$3:B377,B3,C$3:C377,C3)>1`  works for just column `B`

Comment: I'm not completely sure about it, but spreadsheet formulas might actually go to https://superuser.com/ instead of here

Comment: @GuilhermeTaffarelBergamin No they don't. Have [a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635326

Comment: Not what we need @TheMaster Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct mix of [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/) in your [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule:

`=countifs($B$3:$B$377, $B3, $C$3:$C$377, $C3) > 1`

The question does not specify whether columns B and C should be considered tuples or if columns B and C should be considered separately. To handle the latter case, use `countif()`, like this:

`=(countif($B$3:$B$377, $B3) > 1) * (countif($C$3:$C$377, $C3) > 1)`

Comment: Sorry. It does not work.

Comment: Hmm... I think the question is a bit ambiguous because it does not explicitly specify whether B and C should be considered together or separately. Edited the answer to add a solution for the "together" case.

Comment: Maybe I did not phrase it correctly. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I use a `countif` like this, this is only taking consideration column B:

```
=countif($B$2:$B$377, $B2)>1
```

And it look like this:

[image]

To make it work with all the columns, I simply added the columns as individual ranges. Like this:

[image]

**Update:**

For both columns, you can use:

```
=AND(countif($B$2:$B$377, $B2)>1,countif($C$2:$C$377, $C2)>1)
```

Comment: Maybe right. BUT. Not what we asked. We need two conditions.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I didn't take in consideration the the second condition. I updated the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but none of suggested answers or other links worked.

But finally found correct solution.

```
=COUNTIFS(B$3:$B$377,$B3,C$3:$C$377,$C3)>1
```

**This is the only solution.**

Comment: That is not using the correct mix of absolute and relative references.