# Google Sheets: Conditional Format multiple cells equal same value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets

I have a table with numbers filled in columns A, B, C

I want to add conditional formatting:

- If A1 = B1 = C1, highlight in same colour all cells (A1,B1,C1)
- Apply this to the entire columns A, B, C

I can't seem to get the formula right...
Can anybody help out?

Thank you!

I have tried with a few formulas like IF, AND(EXACT.., ARRAYFORMULA...

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-value?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

in conditional formating select range A1:C and use custom formula:

```
=($A1=$B1)*($A1=$C1)
```

Comment: this doesn't work... 
=$A1=$B1 formula will work for 2 columns, but not with the added = sign

Comment: @MarcoDisco updated. try now