# Conditional formatting based on different sheets. Autofill problem

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have this file as a test: [Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tW3CvISfVHeEZ50CUJTio5J2boYonZnmjsLfpA_zxak/edit#gid=0)

It contains 2 sheets (1 & 2)

and two tables (A1:D5) in each sheet

What I want to do is:

To color any not empty cell from sheet1 (filled with either text or value), ONLY IF its equivalent in sheet2 is empty.

what I want to do is clear and working fine in cell A1 in sheet1

- If it's filled, and A1 in sheet2 is empty, it will be colored

- If it's filled, and A1 in sheet2 is filled too, it won't be colored

- If it's empty, it won't be colored no matter what happens in A1 in sheet2

The formula I used in the conditional formatting is:

=IF(A1<>"",ISBLANK(INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!A1")),"")

I think you understand that I've used INDIRECT because conditional formatting doesn't work across the sheets DIRECTLY.

But, in my opinion, I think the problem that this only works for cell A1 is because the reference for the cells in the formula putted in a little quotation marks. That is what prevents it from autofill to expand to affect all cells in the table.

Do you have any ideas??

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: See [if this explanation helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635326/166452)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=LEN(A1)*ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1),,,"Sheet2")))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.. you did the magic 
Thanks a lot.

Can you please explain the idea of this formula?