# Conditional formatting based on a value from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that works as a checklist(Name: Checklist) with "Have" or "Dont Have" as dropdown options and then another sheet(Name: Names) that I would like the cells to be colored green if the cell in "Checklist" is marked "Have" but I don't know how to write the custom formula. If anyone has some pointers that would be great!

I've tried `=INDIRECT("Checklist!B2")="Have"`(Highlights everything green) and
`=INDIRECT("Checklist!B2:H69")="Have"` (Highlights nothing)

Comment: [Edit] to 1. Show the "Apply to" range of the formula you tried and 2. Whether both sheets have the items in the same order(B2 refers to the same item in both sheets)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cells-value/69635326#69635326

Answer (score 1):

If the cells in the Checklist sheet are in the same positions as the cells in the main sheet you could try:

```
=indirect("Checklist!"&cell("address",B2))="Have"
```

in conditional formatting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! It works!

Comment: Glad it was useful. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.