# Conditionally format cell with today's date and additional cells below

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Using conditional formatting I am trying to highlight the cell with today's date with an additional 39 cells below the cell. The way I would like to do this is that if a cell with today's date is anywhere on the sheet, that cell and the 39 cells below it will be highlighted (e.g., green). I read that it not possible to do this without a script. I tried a formula using OFFSET and today's date but this didn't work for me.

The picture I attached is the way the spreadsheet is set up.

[image: Spreadsheet set up as a "calendar"]

This is the formula that I tried:

```
=IF(1:206=TODAY(),OFFSET(TODAY(),,,39)
```

[Spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l2ZTMmhwXj4HoRdj7sRpERHRB8IQnEAzMj6o4iZpdPo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you [edit] to 1. show what you've tried, 2. What about the 40th cell under? 3.  What is the A1 notation of the top left cell in the picture?

Comment: It's not impossible to do this with formula. But it's a bit complicated for the top 39 batch. It's much more complicated to account for unlimited batches below. You're trying to do a approach from the top, but the approach that would work, should come from the bottom - offsetting 39, 38, 37,... according to the current row... to reach the date cell... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635326/

Comment: So by my best understanding you want to say even with a script is not possible to achieve to find the today's date on the sheet and highlight it with +39 cells under the today's date ? My range is always between 1:206 so it's not really unlimited. In my head that script what would look like something today's date +i col 39. Of course I can't make it by myself as I'm not an expert of scripting or creating more advanced formulas.

Comment: @Lev I said it is not impossible... i.e., it is possible  both with formula and script, but just that it's hard. Personally, I would consider restructuring your sheet first for uniformity.

Comment: Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster Unfortunately restructuring the sheet it's not really an option because for the moment it servs its purpose best way. A spreadsheet link is added. I think personally the easiest to do the coloring is via script rather than a formula but I have zero knowledge in that unfortunately .